# Post Data from Laravel 5.4 to WordPress using WordPress Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5.4, wordpress-rest-api, guzzle6

I have two blogs running one is created with Laravel 5.4 and another is running in WordPress.

I am looking for a solution that whenever a POST is created in Laravel it needs to be synchronized with WordPress. I know WordPress but new with Laravel.

In my Laravel application I am using a controller where I am inserting the data in my Laravel database, below is my code for insert:-

```
 public function insert(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);
        $articles = new Vocab;
        $articles->title = $request->input('title');
        $articles->description = $request->input('description');
        $articles->created = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();;
        $articles->save();
        $posttoWordPress = $this->postWordpress($articles->title, $articles->description);
        return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Article saved successfully!');
    }
```

I want at the same time Laravel to post a request to my WordPress and WordPress to create a post for same title and description.

I tried using GuzzleHttp Client, below is the code:-

```
public function postWordpress($title, $description) {       
        $client = new Client([                
                'base_uri' => 'http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/',
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Basic XXXXXXXXX',                
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
                ]
            ]);
        $response = $client->post('posts', [
            'form_params' => [
                'title' => $title,
                'content' => $description
            ],
        ]);
        $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true); 
    }
```

I am usin Basic authorization for WordPress and it is working fine with POSTMAN. When I am submitting data, error is showing:-

```
Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
[file] /var/www/html/lv/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
```

However when I open the API url (http://XXX.XX.XX.XXX/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts) from my browser it is working fine.

Please give me some suggestion or few code example so that I can achieve this task.

Thanks

Comment: You probably will not get a good response here as you have not described or shown anything you have tried.  You might want to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and edit your question.  I use https://github.com/corcel/corcel in a Laravel/WP project, though I don't do anything like what you describe, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I am not getting idea how to start with this that's why nothing have described. I will update once I have some progress. Thanks again.

Comment: Corcel can be used only if a direct access to database is possible. to use the REST API look here : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: @mmm You're right, I missed the mention of the API in the title.  Corcel won't help here.